# Problem In Installing Ubuntu GCC

Tags: software-installation, windows-8, gcc, compiler

I have installed Ubuntu as a guest OS on Windows. Well I am getting this error when I try to install GCC:

[image: Error]

Comment: Is another installation still running?

Comment: No other installation is not running